# Moving to an SSD with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd

Disclaimer: I've been digging around for a few days and didn't get what I was looking for in terms of answers, so I'm asking here.

I've recently purchased an 80g SSD drive to use as my boot up and OS parition. I've got a windows 7 desktop with two 1TB (raid0) disks currently and I'm not sure where to start in terms of copying / moving the OS.

I suppose that doing a fresh install isn't out of the question, but I've got an upgrade disk from Vista that I'd have to deal with. Where do I begin?

Comment: Fresh install is gonna be the best bet for that part.

Comment: It's likely a fresh install is best, but I'd like to know more about your current set-up before making a suggestion. How is the RAID configured/partitioned

Answer (score 2):

Just do a clean install of Windows 7. You can install Windows 7 from scratch with Windows 7 upgrade media ("honor system").